# Vue.js - Watch changes in JSON file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

Here idea is to watch changes made in JSON file and if some value is changed it automatically changes the condition v-if.

```
<div id="app">
 <div v-if="content == 'one'">
   <p>Content one</p>
 </div>
 <div v-else-if="content == 'two'">
   <p>Contentn two</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Now the tricky part comes, I need to be able after build to change the JSON file, and automatically to change what will be shown.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   content: ''
  },
  methods: {
    // import of JSON and value that will assign value to this.content
        // Now value can be 'one' or 'two'
  }
})
```

Comment: Its not possible to watch changes inside a json file. To properly watch changes the value you're watching should be reactive.

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible to watch for changes inside a json file.
What you could do is set the json to a reactive property and check for changes on there.
When changing the JSON you also need to update the reactive property so the watcher gets triggered

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   content: ''
  },
  watch: {
    content: function (val) {
      // do something when content has changed
    },
    },
  methods: {
    importJson() {
            // import json and set contents to content
    },
    saveJson(newJSON) {
        this.content = newJSON
      // Somehow save the json data to the json file
    }
  }
})
```

You should now that changes to a JSON file are not persistent.

Comment: I did that but it won't work. I solve this issue with axios. :) 

methods: {
    updateData () {
      axios.get('../static/client/data.json').then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
        this.dataClient = response.data
      })
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.updateData()
  }

Now when you change JSON file in 'dist' folder after build and refresh browser it will load new value.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue with axios. :)

```
methods: {
        updateData () {
          axios.get('../static/client/data.json').then(response => {
            console.log(response.data)
            this.dataClient = response.data
          })
        }
      },
      created () {
        this.updateData()
      }
```

Now when you change JSON file in 'dist' folder after build and refresh browser it will load new value.